# Call a function after loading an URL

Tags: javascript, html, url

I want to execute a certain function after an specified URL loads.
I tried to set an interval to detect the url I want, but it isn't working so far.
here's the code I have for calling the function:

```
pub.startup = function() {
var currURL = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.host;
window.setInterval(currURL, 1000);
if (currURL == 'www.google.com')
FunctionToCall();
}
```

Hope to get some help.

Comment: You can put this javascript in a page, but when the page is reloaded, due to a click on a link or a submit of a form, the entire page is reloaded and all the javascripts are "trashed" so you can't intercept the reloading in that way. What you can do is change the behavior of all the links in your page and set a function on their onclick that when is clicked you intercept the url (taking it from the href of the element), check it, call the function and return true to let the load go, but after the user exited from your page your function ends to live. I hope I was clear :P

Comment: you cannot run code from page1.htm after a new page loads and replaces it in the browser.

Comment: Is that URL just a silly example, or do you really want to detect every time the browser loads Google?

Comment: Are you loading the page inside an `iframe` or opening it in another window through `window.open`? If it is in the same window, then it's as @rascio said.

Comment: I will use it in a firefox's statusbar addon, so i want to detect a certain url (i used google as example there) and keep running the function while the page is opened, if the page is closed then the function should stop. i've tried to put a function instead of that variable, Willem Mulder.. but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
pub.startup = function() {
    function checkCurrURL() {
        var currURL = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.host;
        if (currURL == 'www.google.com')
            FunctionToCall();
    }
    window.setInterval(checkCurrURL, 1000);
};
```

Comment: that doesn't work unfortunately. I've already found a solution. Thank's anyway!!

Comment: Please add your own answer and accept it as such... Or possibly accept one of the given answers if it comes close.

Answer (score 0):

window.setInterval expects a function (or arbitrary code) to execute. You supply it with a variable, which won't work.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval